# Log file with awk

Tags: bash, logging, awk

I have this menu script working. I'm supposed to write a code that will record in a log file how many times the menu script was used and what option was used in the menu.

```
#\usr\bin\bash
clear;
echo "Welcome"
while [ $option!=7 ]
do
clear;
printf "\n\t\tMenu Principal"
printf "\n1)Pega 2 "
printf "\n2)Pega 3 "
printf "\n3)Pega 4 "
printf "\n4)Loto "
printf "\n5)Revancha "
printf "\n6)Ver Log File "
printf "\n7)Salir "
read option
case $option in
    '1')
        clear;
        echo "Los numeros del Pega 2 son : "
        awk 'BEGIN { for(i=1;i<=2;i++) print int(9*rand())}'>temp
        cat temp ; sleep 3
        ;;

    '2')
        clear;
        echo "Los numeros del Pega 3 son : "
        awk 'BEGIN { for(i=1;i<=3;i++) print int(9*rand())}'>temp
        cat temp ; sleep 3
        ;;

    '3')
        clear;
        echo "Los numeros del Pega 4 son : "
        awk 'BEGIN { for(i=1;i<=4;i++) print int(9*rand())}'>temp
        cat temp ; sleep 3
        ;;

    '4')
        clear;
        echo "Los numeros de la Loteria son : "
        awk 'BEGIN { for(i=1;i<=6;i++) print int(46*rand())}'>temp
        cat temp ; sleep 5
        ;;

    '5')
        clear;
        echo "Los numeros de la Revancha son : "
        awk 'BEGIN { for(i=1;i<=6;i++) print int(46*rand())}'>temp
        cat temp ; sleep 5
        ;;

    '6')
        clear;

        ;;

    '7')
        clear;
        echo "Gracias por participar! " ; sleep 2
        exit
        ;;

esac
done
```

In the option 6 is where the log file should go. Any pointers?

Comment: You want `while [ "$option" -ne 7 ]`, not `while [ $option!=7 ]`. The latter is only going to do what you expect in a very small set of cases.

Answer (score 1):

The part of the script needed I think it's more [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) than [awk](/questions/tagged/awk). First you will need some variables to keep statistics of how many times execute each option. I would use an associative array for that, if your [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) version accepts it:

First, as first instruction declare it:

```
declare -A options
```

And for each option executed increment its position in the hash:

```
...
read option
((++options[ $option ]))
total_executed_times=0
case $option in
...
```

So, when clicked the sixth option, traverse the array to print results:

```
'6')
    for i in "${!options[@]}"; do
        total_executed_times=$(($total_executed_times + ${options[$i]}))
        echo "Option $i executed ${options[$i]} times"
    done
    echo "Times the menu was used: $total_executed_times"
    sleep 5
    clear;
    ;;
```

Note that options not selected won't be printed and there is no order of keys, but could be a task to improve if you wish.

I executed to make a test, captured it before the `clear` and it yielded:

```
Option  6  executed 2 times
Option  3  executed 1 times
Option  4  executed 2 times
Option  1  executed 4 times
Option  2  executed 1 times
Times the menu was used: 10
```